# Image Button cannot be cast to widget Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried the following from similar stack overflow 
Clean ,Build Project 
Restart Eclipse

I also tried update everything : from SDK and Eclipse plugin
Restart emulator etc

Log Cat output:

```
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ass2/com.example.ass2.MP3Player}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.example.ass2.MP3Player.onCreate(MP3Player.java:30)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-26 22:11:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 11 more
```

Code

```
public class MP3Player extends Activity{

    Button prev , play , stop , next , choosefiles;
    ArrayAdapter<Song> adaptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(R.layout.mp3player);


    //Bitmap         mDummyAlbumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy_album_art);


     prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.prev);
     play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
     stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
     next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
     prev.setOnClickListener(new OnPress());
     play.setOnClickListener(new OnPress());
     stop.setOnClickListener(new OnPress());
     next.setOnClickListener(new OnPress());

    List<Song> playlist = new ArrayList<Song>();

    System.out.println("Before adapter on creat");

    Song test= new Song("sakis","rouvas","name","path");
    playlist.add(test);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(this,
            R.layout.list_row, playlist);
    list.setAdapter(adaptor);
    registerForContextMenu(list);

    System.out.println("after adapter on craet");
}     `
```

Comment: Are these `Buttons` declared as `ImageButtons` in your xml?

Comment: @codeMaigc yes they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ImageButton is not a child of Button, no matter what the name suggests. See
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html
It extends ImageView, not Button.
One of the lines

```
 prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.prev);
 play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
 stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
 next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
```

causes this error because the view is an ImageButton, not a Button. In fact, since you only assign OnClickListeners to the views, casting them seems not necessary. "View" will do. This, of course, depends on the rest of your code but in general you should not cast to child views if you don't use the child methods. Especially for switching between Buttons and ImageButtons this can be a pain.

Comment: many many thanks It works now :)  And thank you for all the rest of the information .