# When I run app i got this error

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio I got problem when I run app  (( on create)) system crash i think this is because i call

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

and my component (imageButton)

on

R.layout.home

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Context context; //Declare the variable context

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    -
    -
    -

    -

    -
    Button Buying =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    Buying.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       // @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TempActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

this is error message

Process: com.example.tariqlab.ar_right_draw_application, PID: 19212
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tariqlab.ar_right_draw_application/com.example.tariqlab.ar_right_draw_application.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2689)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2756)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5940)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at com.example.tariqlab.ar_right_draw_application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119

Comment: you should also add logcat

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039727/image-button-cannot-be-cast-to-widget-button

Comment: put your logcat with xml code

Comment: post your logcat error please

Answer (score 0):

use only

```
Button Buying =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

and check your id is right as per you define in xml file

Comment: Button Buying =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton); -- not defined in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    --- but it is defined in setContentView(R.layout.home);